# How to access multiple array of object data?

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Id] => 23490
    [Receipt] => 7684454
    [DateTime] => 2019-04-23T19:17:28.000
    [Type] => Consumer
    [Transactions] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [PacId] => 90
                    [Label] => GDHSGSHE562543
                    [Name] => VHSS - AS-89
                    [Sold] => 27.9
                    [Unit] => Grams
                    [Abbreviation] => g
                    [Price] => 198
                    [State] => 
                    [Date] => 
                    [LastModified] => 2019-04-23T19:17:29+00:00
                )

        )

    [Final] => 
    [Date] => 
    [LastModified] => 2019-04-23T19:17:29+00:00
)
```

I am using below code but not working for me. I want to access all the name with values using below code but not working for me. How can I solve this?

```
$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($f_data);

            while ($iterator->valid()) {

                if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {
                    // print all children
                    foreach ($iterator->getChildren() as $key => $value) {
                        echo $key . ' : ' . $value . "\n";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "No children.\n";
                }

                $iterator->next();
            }
```

I want output as below

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [Id] => 23490
        [Receipt] => 7684454
        [DateTime] => 2019-04-23T19:17:28.000
        [Type] => Consumer
        [Transactions] => Array
        [PacId] => 90
        [Label] => GDHSGSHE562543
        [Name] => VHSS - AS-89
        [Sold] => 27.9
        [Unit] => Grams
        [Abbreviation] => g
        [Price] => 198
        [State] => 
        [Date] => 
        [LastModified] => 2019-04-23T19:17:29+00:00
        [Final] => 
        [Date] => 
        [LastModified] => 2019-04-23T19:17:29+00:00
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`$f_data->Transactions` is an array containing an object, so it will throw you that error:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

---

## The `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class

The much easier solution is to also use the [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) class.

```php
$obj = (your_object_here);

var_dump(flat($obj));

function flat($iterable) {
    $arr = [];
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($iterable));
    
    foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
        $arr[$key] = $value;
    }
    
    return (object)$arr;
}
```

[Test it on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0vM9mE)

---

## The `RecursiveArrayIterator` class only

An other solution may to have a recursive function that will call itself when the iterator meet an element with children (array or object).

```php
$obj = (your_object_here);

var_dump(flat($obj));

function flat($iterable) {
    $arr = [];
    
    $iterator = (get_class($iterable) === RecursiveArrayIterator::class)
        ? $iterable
        : new RecursiveArrayIterator($iterable);
    
    while($iterator->valid()) {
        if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {
            $arr = array_merge($arr, (array)flat($iterator->getChildren()));
        } else {
            $arr[$iterator->key()] = $iterator->current();
        }
        
        $iterator->next();
    }
    
    return (object)$arr;
}
```

[Test it on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MiRKW)

---

## The`foreach` statement

Or you could simply use a recursive `foreach` statement.

```php
$obj = (your_object_here);

var_dump(flat($obj));

function flat($iterable) {
    $arr = [];
    
    foreach ($iterable as $key => $element) {
        if (is_array($element) || is_object($element)) {
            $arr = array_merge($arr, (array)flat($element));
        } else {
            $arr[$key] = $element;
        }
    }
    
    return (object)$arr;
}
```

[Test it on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/RpMeg)

Comment: Thanks for reply
Its working but i need result as array of object
But above solution giving result as below....

stdClass Object
(
    [Id] => 23490
    [Receipt] => 7684454
    [DateTime] => 2019-04-23T19:17:28.000
    [Type] => Consumer
    [PacId] => 90
    [Label] => GDHSGSHE562543
    [Name] => VHSS - AS-89
    [Sold] => 27.9
    [Unit] => Grams
    [Abbreviation] => g
    [Price] => 198
    [State] => 
    [Date] => 
    [LastModified] => 2019-04-23T19:17:29+00:00
    [Final] => 
    [Date] => 
    [LastModified] => 2019-04-23T19:17:29+00:00
)

Comment: Each snippet of my answer returns nothing. They're just echoing `KEY = VALUE`. Please, edit your first post and show us what is the desired output.

Comment: Ya i have edited first post, Plz recommend some solution.
Thanks